# How to convert java.awt.Image to byte arrays in java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have the `java.awt.Image` object and I want to convert it into bytes array that contain RGB value of each pixel. For example,

```
byte[][][] image_color = new byte[3][image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];
```

Big Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the overloads of [`java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29), or the methods of [`java.awt.image.Raster`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html), which can be obtained through [`BufferredImage.getRaster()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRaster%28%29). You can find some sample usage [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/javase/src/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/BufferedImageLuminanceSource.java?spec=svn1716&r=1697).